# How to lower brightness with UISlider so that it is lower than the lowest brightness setting available to the user?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a clock application that is designed to be used to display the time at night. I want to find a way to make the brightness lower than what the user can make it, such as what is done in this app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/night-clock/id293660080?mt=8). I have tried UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(0), but this only goes as dark as the user can make it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dim all contents displayed by your app.

Instead of adjusting all colors you can get the same effect by adding an overlay view. Set the `backgroundColor` of this view to black with alpha `0.5`, and then play with the alpha value.